# If $F(x)=(F_1(x),\dots, F_n(x))$, is always possible to find $F_i(x)=\min\{F_1(x),\dots, F_n(x)\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

Let $n\ge 2$, ($n$ finite) and $F:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^n$ be a positive function, meaning that
$$ F(x)=(F_1(x),\dots, F_n(x))$$
and $F_i(x)\ge 0$ for any $i\in\{1,\dots, n\}$.

My question is: is always possible to find the minimum (or the maximum) between the $n$ components of $F$? More precisely, is it possible to find $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $F_i(x)=\min\{F_1(x),\dots, F_n(x)\}$?

On the one hand, I think that the answer is yes because $F_i(x)\in\mathbb R$ for any $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, which means that $(F_1(x),\dots, F_n(x))$ is vector made of real numbers and I can always find the minimum (or maximum) between $n$ real numbers.

On the other hand, I am confused about the presence of the variable $x$.

Anyone could please help me in understanding this?

Comment: If $n$ is finite then yes it's always possible. Otherwise the minimum might not exist.

Comment: @BenjaminWang, yes, $n$ is finite. May I ask your help to understand the role of $x$?

Comment: Are you doing this point-wise? i.e., for a fixed value of $x$? Because in that case, you just have a finite list of finite numbers, from which you can certainly ascertain the maximum/minimum. If your minimum also runs over values of $x$, then it might not be possible (for the same reason that $\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f(x)$ might not exist)

Comment: There isn't one $i$ the works for all $x,$ but given $x,$ you can certainly find $i.$

Comment: The real question is, what do you mean by "find?" If you want an algorithm, then the $F_i$ have to be computable. But this goes into a big question of what it means to get e real number from a computable function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F_1(x) = x, F_2(x) = 1 - x, x \in [0, 1]$. Then,
$$
    \min\{F_1(x), F_2(x)\} = \begin{cases} x, \text{ if } 0 \le x \le 1/2 \\ 1 - x, \text{ if } 1/2 < x \le 1 \end{cases}
$$

There is no $i \in \{1,2\}$ such that $F_i(x) = \min\{F_1(x), F_2(x)\}$ **for all** $x \in [0, 1]$. But, for a **fixed** $x \in [0, 1]$, you can find $i \in \{1,2\}$ such that $F_i(x) = \min\{F_1(x), F_2(x)\}$. In particular,
$$
    i = \begin{cases} 1, \text{ if } 0 \le x < 1/2 \\ 2, \text{ if } 1/2 \le x \le 1  \end{cases}
$$
You may even notice that when $x = 1/2$, the choice for $i$ is not unique, as $F_1(1/2) = F_2(1/2) = 1/2$.

In conclusion, the statement:
$$
   \exists i, \forall x, F_i(x) = \min\{F_1(x), \ldots, F_n(x)\}
$$
is in general, false. But the statement:
$$
   \forall x, \exists i \text{ (may depends on }x \text{) }, F_i(x) = \min\{F_1(x), \ldots, F_n(x)\}
$$
is true.